# how to call method from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

How to call method from code-behind.I use asp.net n c#.I'm not familiar in .net environment.This is my example c# in code-behind:

```
public void HandleAction()
{
    //HandleAction content
}

public void WriteTable()
{
           //WriteTable content
}
```

I want to call it in markup page. I have use Response.Write to write the data in webpage.

Comment: When do you want to call the method? When the user presses a button? When an event occurs? On post-back?

Comment: Generally in the markup, you can call functions from the code behind or embedding code in the markup using <%....%> and between <% %> you write your code. For instance if you want to get the user name, <%=Page.User.Identity.Name%>. So if you want to get the value that a function, which is defined in the code behind file, returns, you could simple write <%=GetValue(parameter1,parameter2,...)%>

Comment: I want to call when page load because the WriteTable method is use write the table in the page..I already try put <%=WriteTable%>, but it error "Cannot convert method group 'WriteTable' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intent to invoke the method?"...thank for answer

Comment: I have found the answer..It should be <%WriteTable();%>..Thank everyone in advance :D

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer..It should be call like this in markup `<%WriteTable();%>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call c# function in markup by using server tags

```
<%= function() %>
```

Please find more detail here :-http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you have to use RegisterClientScriptBlock.
This may help you.

```
public void HandleAction()
{
    //HandleAction content

    string jScript;
    jScript="<script>alert ('Javascript block of code executed')</script>";
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("keyClientBlock",jScript);

}
```

By using the above code you can register a client side function also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Methodname is the name of your c# method..

You can call it the page load or button click or any event that causes a postback..

    <%=MethodName()%>
```

Comment: I want call when page load..Thank you for answer..I put this <%=WriteTable()%> it also error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'".