# Calling codebehind method from markup and is throwing javascript error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a div tag that has a click event and the method I'm trying to call is from the codebehind.

This is my div tag

```
<div class="DivA" runat="server" id="ThisDiv" onclick="<%ClickMe();%>"></div>
```

The method is a simple

```
public void ClickMe()
    {
        Response.Redirect("www.google.ca");
    }
```

I'm just testing this before I add the real stuff to it. The error that it is throwing is...

```
JavaScript critical error at line 16, column 49 in http://localhost:24307/DIVPAGE.aspx

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

this is the line that it is giving me

```
<div id="ThisDiv" class="DivA" onclick="&lt;%ClickMe();%>"></div>
```

I have tried changing the

```
 <%ClickMe();%>
```

to

```
 <%=ClickMe()%>
```

But that throws the same error. Another thing I don't understand is when you look at the line with the error that it is missing the runat tag and has added other characters to the onclick event.

Thanks

Comment: Checked it, It didn't explain much, well at least in a way for me to understand it. I've checked and one of the ways is the way to do it but it causes an error for me. I don't know much with JavaScript, that's why I want to what I need done in the codebehind. I do know that if I was using a JavaScript function that the onclick would work, but as I mentioned I don't know enough in JavaScript to do what I need done.

Comment: Server code is interpreted **before** client code. When the server is done processing, everything is output as **plain text**. You can't interact directly with the server from the client or the other way around. Anything the server outputs has to be able to be interpreted by the browser; that is HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. It's very hard to explain without a basic understanding of the concept. That's why I suggest you invest some time reading about the "client-server" model until you **understand**, then you'll see why your question is not possible, at least not the way you think it is.

Comment: I've read it over a couple times. I'm just confused that I can use an asp button and use that onlick method to call its onclick method from the code behind. But can't with a div's onclick event even though I am using runat server. So i figured that there would be no reason not to be able to call a method on the div's onclick method. I had a link from a post on here stating that you can call a codebehind method from the mark up... that link is..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739062/how-to-call-method-from-code-behind?lq=1

Comment: I need to access the method because I am iterating through a dataset on the click event and changing the innertext of the divs. So maybe I could have the div click event call a javascript function and have the javascript function access the method?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with ASP so maybe it's possible with that magic `runat` attribute. Maybe somebody more experienced can explain in more detail. But the client-server concept still applies, that is the basics of how the web works. If `ClickMe` doesn't output valid JavaScript you'll keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Using the runat="server" tag allows me to access the div by Id and can change attributes and properties of the div tag in the code behind. If I'm correct the runat tag makes it server side and not client side. I added the JavaScript tag because it was throwing the error

Comment: It's been a really long time since I had the misfortune of doing webforms programming, but what he is trying to do is actually very close to working. I can't remember the syntax but asp.net will inject some javascript to post to the server and call a server-side method. Not one of Microsoft's best ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You have a concept problem here, do this, and test it will work:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbClickMe" runat="server" OnClick="ClickMe">
   <div class="DivA" id="ThisDiv">
      The Click Me Button!
   </div>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

That's it, when runat=server is specified ASP.NET page parser will process the element as server side, so for this elements/controls no server tags in markup are allowed except data binding tags inside control templates. So to call you method you have to put a runat server on a control that haves the Click event, this is the case of the LinkButton, inside of him you can put your div for some specific styling of your UI.

Also not that, if you really want to have the your div behaving like that, there is no problem in complicating what is simple, but in that case please do this instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbClickMe" runat="server" OnClick="ClickMe" Visible="False"></asp:LinkButton>
<div class="DivA" id="ThisDiv" onclick="<%= Page.GetPostBackEventReference(lbClickMe) %>"></div>
```

The GetPostBackEventReference extracts the javascript code necessary to simulate your link button click, but once more is preferable to use directly the link button if you can.

Hope it helps,

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call server-side C# methods from the DOM like that. You can only call JavaScript functions in an HTMLElement's `onclick` handler.

It is correct that you can call server-side methods using the template language, however this will be executed at the time of rendering the page; you could, for example, render the results of that server-side method, but you can't use a server-side method as a handler for a client-side event. The onclick event on a DOM element can only call a JavaScript function.

ASP web controls also have an `OnClick` event attribute, which is probably what's confusing you; this is different from the onclick event attribute on DOM elements (ASP will create additional code for its web controls, e.g. in case of an asp:button). This works using ViewState and a postback to the server. The `onclick` event for a DOM element however won't do those things for you.

Adding `runat="server"` will convert your element to an ASP control, however it will only be an HtmlControl. In the case of a `<div>`, it will be an [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y7zx0ww%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which simply writes out the `onclick` attribute of your element as it is.

Comment: I thought the result would be calling the method from the code behind. Your answer brings up another question, why can I use the onclick handler with an asp button, which calls the onlclick method from the codebehind, but not the onclick event handler on a div tag which has the runat server to call a method from the code behind?

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739062/how-to-call-method-from-code-behind says that you can call a method from the codebehind from the markup

Comment: @user2970223 I updated my answer; your problem is that you're mixing HTML syntax with ASP webform control syntax which performs some magic for you that doesn't work with plain HTML

Comment: I understand that a div and html would be clientside, but adding the runat=server tag changes that because, if I'm correct, the runat tag changes the div from clientside to a server side control. That is why I can interact with the div's elements from the code behind.

Comment: @user2970223 yes, it changes it to a server-side control, however this will only be an [HtmlControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.HtmlControls(v=vs.100).aspx), not a WebControl; the HtmlControl doesn't do anything with the onclick attribute, it simply writes this out into the document, whereas an ASP button will create additional code; you can check the documentation for the available properties; e.g. an asp button has [OnClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick(v=vs.100).aspx), which is why it works as you have seen

Comment: @user2970223 also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - apparently you can use `onserverclick` from some HtmlControls

Answer (score 0):

The `<%= %>` syntax emits a string, it doesn't *do* anything, like a redirect.

You need to do your redirect client-side with this javascript:

```
  window.location = 'http://my.url.com';
```

If you need to interact with server side code, you need to do so with AJAX communicating to a web service to get the URL you need, and then performing the redirect described above.

**Update**

Sorry lads, brain freeze.

Yes, indeed, you can inject a string that will be evaluated as a click handler, but the handler must be a javascript function, not a server-side one! Once the page is rendered, it can no longer interact with the server save for communicating with a web service (or if we want to get technical, web sockets as well).

Comment: No, he is doing WebForms programming, this isn't necessary, you can call server-side code with runat="server" controls, it injects the javascript to do it for you.

Comment: That was just for testing before I add the real code. What I have is 5 divs, one holds a question and the remaining 4 contain answers. I wanted to call the codebehind method on the div onclick event, then the method would iterate to the next row in a dataset that has a question and for answers then change the div's innerhtml to the next row. I did find a work around though, instead of using divs as buttons I'm going to use css to change the look of the aspbutton and work with it that way. I just figured I would be able to call a method with the divs onclick

Comment: @grennis, you are right. I am doing webforms, and using the runat tag, I assumed that I could have the divs onclick method call the codebehind method. Because adding the runat tag changes the control to a serverside code. I think I caused a lot of confusion for tagging this with javascript. I'm going to edit to remove the javascript tag

Comment: Yes you need to target this question for WebForms also. Make that more clear. This hit the completely wrong audience.

Comment: @user2970223 You are using a HTML control with `runat=server`, so it does get parsed by the ASP.net runtime, *but* its `click` attribute is still client side. If you use `<asp:panel runat="server" click="SomeFunction()" />`, then the click attribute will reference a server side function.

Comment: @ChrisHardie I was trying to use css, because at some point I'm going to have to start working with the mvc framework and I won't have the luxury of using asp controls like I can in webforms. So I figured I would start trying new things. Your comments are good though because I'm learning a few things that will hopefully help when I go to MVC and razor

Comment: I'm a HUGE fan of MVC, it's hard to go back to WebForms (though IO have to at times).

Comment: I have a hard time grasping the framework. I keep trying to relate it to webforms. I look at the view as the markup, the controller as code behind and the model as a class. I'm trying to hard to relate MVC to webforms that's why I'm procrastinating on crossing over.

Comment: Stop stop STOP procrastinating. MVC just spits out HTML, which sounds primitive, but it does an INCREDIBLE job in helping you do it. Learn HTML, and CSS, and Javascript, and learn to love MVC helping you leverage those technologies without getting in the way.

Comment: I want to stop procrastinating but I have a hard time understanding the architecture, having to add controllers to this and views to that so this would work. Its a lot different from webforms. I haven't found anything really on transitioning from webforms to mvc, other than some person writing an article explaining their new found love of mvc and not explaining anything. I have read that being a webform developer gives more leverage when transitioning to mvc but never an explanation on why or how.

Comment: Well, knowing a bit about the ASP.Net runtime helps, but they are indeed completely different, for good reason. They execute complety different philosophies. Check out www.asp.net (of course) and spend the time with the tutorials.

Comment: I'm going to have to check out those tutorials because all the books start off with you modifying an existing website and I like to learn it from the bottom up. When I start any developing I always start off with an empty workspace, and I haven't found any mvc tutorial for C# that starts off from an empty workspace and build from the ground up.

Comment: @user2970223, here you have a very good MVC 4 tutorial for total newbies to MVC. [Intro to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4). It's simple but good enough to cover all the fundamentals. Starting from scratch is sort of complex because there would be so much to cover that any tutorial would end up being a book. If that's what you really want, then you should read a book on the subject...